# how to get AWS instance ssh signature and store it in an AWS secret

Tags: ssh, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, ssh-tunnel

I have a terraform module that creates an AWS EC2 instance. I want to generate a known_hosts entry for this instance and store it in an AWS secret (context: a CI/CD will later use this secret to tunnel through the instance to run kubectl, so that the k8s API server is not public).

I cannot use https://registry.terraform.io/providers/luma-planet/sshclient for now.

So I am using a `local-exec` provisioner that calls the standard `ssh-keyscan` available on the OS. However the output cannot be put in a local var directly, for later reference in the AWS secret.

So I save the file locally, and reference it in the secret (this uses terraform 1.4 released last week, but same issue using `null_resource` with prior versions (where `terraform_data` does not exist)):

```
resource "aws_instance" "bastion" {
  key_name      = "key_name"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  ami           = "ami-..."
  subnet_id     = "subnet-..."
  
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-..."] # must allow port 22
}

resource "terraform_data" "ssh_keyscan_bastion" {
  input = aws_instance.bastion.id
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "ssh-keyscan -t rsa ${aws_instance.bastion.public_dns} > ${path.root}/known_hosts_bastion"
  }
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "bastion" {
  name = "bastion"
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "bastion" {
  depends_on = [terraform_data.ssh_keyscan_bastion]

  secret_id     = aws_secretsmanager_secret.bastion.id
  secret_string = jsonencode({
    public_dns   = aws_instance.bastion.public_dns
    ssh_known_hosts = file("${path.root}/known_hosts_bastion")
  })
}
```

A terraform apply will abort plan because it tries to load the file before the local-exec has run.

Is there a better way of putting the bastion ssh signature into the AWS secret?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I had missed from the docs that `file()` is only for files that already exist before the apply, whereas the `local_file` data source will wait till the resource it depends on has run. So I was able to add this to the .tf file:

```
resource "terraform_data" "ssh_keyscan_bastion" {
  input = aws_instance.bastion.id
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "ssh-keyscan -t rsa ${aws_instance.bastion.public_dns} > ${path.root}/known_hosts_bastion"
  }
}

data "local_file" "known_hosts" {
  depends_on = [terraform_data.ssh_keyscan_bastion]
  filename   = "${path.root}/known_hosts_bastion"
}
```

Then the secret becomes

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "bastion" {
...
    ssh_known_hosts = data.local_file.known_hosts.content
...
}
```